# Type annotations of objects to the correct class in Python/Eclipse

Tags: python, eclipse, types, casting

I'm using Eclipse for developing some Python based application.

Very often I pass some class object to methods. So how can I say to the eclipse that this particular variable is of type Class A. For ex.

```
def foo(var1,var2):
    ''' var1 is of type Class A, and var2 is of type Class B'''
    var1.a = 10
    var2.b = 'xyz'
```

I can use all these ways, problems is that Eciplse can't give the variable hints for all these member variables for `Class A` and `Class B`. I've to go and check the member variables manually. This is very hectic and error prone. Is there any way I can tell eclipse/python that `var1` is of type `Class A` and `var2` is of type `class B`?

Comment: Give your variables meaningful names, and you never have a need to think about types (well, most of the time :-)).

Comment: I am sure someone somewhere has accomplished a mentionable level of mutability between similar object types.

Comment: @Helper Method - the point isn't for the programmer to not think about types, it's for an IDE to look up likely methods and documentation.

Answer (score 1):

There exists no such thing as type casting in Python. There's type coercion that happens in arithmetic expressions, e.g., but that's something different. [As I explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4110975/python-eclipse-type-casting-intellisense-work-around/4111281#4111281), there's no sensible way for Eclipse to do what you want it do do. Since Python 3 there are [type annotations in function definitions](http://docs.python.org/py3k/reference/compound_stmts.html#function-definitions), as propopsed in [PEP-3107](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3107/), which may or may not be used in the future by programs like PyDev.

Until then, instead of fighting [duck typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing), you should embrace its power.

Comment: thanks for the comments.I was curious to see how the professional Python programmers manages hundreds of Classes in "duck typing" way.I came from the Embedded domain to Python. So I didn't have the luxury of intellisense or something like that with C or Assembly languages. But Python made me lazy..;).....

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue ... as far as I've been searching, you can't do that!

[Typing Casting in Python Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4726106/typing-casting-in-python-question)